# What is the emotion that propels UX people?

Tags: users, emotion

At my workplace, I see UX folks being emotional and even defensive about users. They feel a 'duty of care' for the end user, as if they know them and deeply care for them. My question to this UX community is whether User Experience is the only way you care about users? Or do you feel for others more than usual? Am I describing empathy?

Comment: See also: Articles about [Empathy in UX Design](http://www.paulolyslager.com/empathy-in-ux-design/) collated by @paul-olyslager

Comment: I think this is a subjective question.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello yeah its subjective. I am not looking for a specific answer here, but perspectives of UX practitioners on what motivates them about their craft.

Comment: Then you shouldn't ask it. Review the [help/dont-ask] pages about what you should and shouldn't ask; this belongs to the latter category (every answer is equally valid, there is no actual problem to be solved, and this isn't a constructive subjective question).

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello I don't think every answer would be equally valid. Also, its certainly a constructive question as it aims to define the core values behind the profession of UX. Anyway, I am content with the answer by Benjamin S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emotional and defensive behavior of UX professionals is likely a combination of empathy and professional passion. Any professional that is passionate about their career and domain of expertise will become emotional or defensive in certain situations; this is not a trait unique to UX professionals.

That said, empathy itself is a critical aspect of the UX profession; I would argue that it is the core tenet of the profession. I would recommend these two articles to gain an understanding of empathy's role in UX:

- http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/realizing-empathy-part-1-art/
- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/10/04/user-experience-using-empathy-to-empower-your-users/

As far as your question of if User Experience is the only way to care about your users, I would say it depends on the definition and scope of UX. Looking at Nielson and Norman's definition:

"User experience encompasses all aspects of the end-user's interaction with the company, its services, and its products."

With this definition UX includes the interaction with a call center employee, the decisions of a business manager, and the cleanliness provided by the maintenance staff. All of these and more influence and impact the end-user's interaction with the company. This would mean that, while yes, User Experience is the only way to care about users, it is largely due to the definition of UX being a process for caring about users.

UX Professionals *may* show more empathy than other professions, but UX folks do not have a monopoly on the user experience.

We all have a part to play in our 'duty of care' for others.

Comment: "We all have a part to play in our 'duty of care' for others." <-- I just wish others than UX folk on a team would actually realize it :-\

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich You are absolutely correct that we all have our part to play. I would propose that it is our responsibility as UX professionals to help educate and foster that "duty of care" in other professions and teams. We can't provide a stellar experience alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far I wasn't able to achieve it. I don't know if it's beceause I'm a young blood and noone listens to me by definition or because I'm unable to transfer my insights to others (and I tried several approaches... lectures, workshops, literature, lead by example...). It really starts to frustrate me.

Comment: Our entire job as UX professionals exists because a better experience directly equates to more sales, more customer satisfaction and more profit.